# How many times do you have to hit an Enderman with a diamond sword?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How many times do you have to hit an Enderman with a diamond sword?

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a resource location service. This information is quite easily available on MCWiki - just take the HP of an enderman and divide by the damage points of a diamond sword.

Answer (score 3):

it depends on what for enchantment you have on it

if you talk about a diamond sword without a enchantment then it will take 6 hits

Answer (score 3):

Use [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki) to answer questions like this.

According to the [wiki on Enderman](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman), they have 40 health points

According to the [wiki on sword damage](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sword#Java_Edition), the diamond sword delivers 7 points of damage.

40 / 7 = 5.7 which means 6 hits to kill them.

---

If you want information on enchanted swords then you can head over to the [enchanting wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting).  In this case, lets look at [sharpness](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Sharpness):

> Adds 1 extra damage for the first level, and 0.5 for each additional level.

You have to calculate the damage for the sword then divide the enderman's health points.  As an example, here is a sharpness 5 diamond sword:

Diamond sword 7 points + 1 point for first sharpness level + (0.5 X 4) points for last four levels = 10 points of damage

40 enderman health / 10 damage = 4 hits

Answer (score 0):

It took me 2 hits to kill 1 enderman with a Sharpness 5, Knocknback 2, Fire Aspect 2, Looting 3, Unbreaking 3 and Meanding 1 Sword. I killed the Ender Dragon with a Sharpness 5, Knocknback 2, Fire Aspect 2, Looting 3, Unbreaking 3 and Meanding 1 Sword. With this sword it took me 53 hits to kill the Ender Dragon.

Answer (score -1):

About six hits is what I think.